# Slow mysql response query

Tags: java, eclipse, database-connection

**HI,**
i have made a connection with java and driver mysql in eclipse,all is ok but when i try to send a request to database,the response is very slow,it take more than 1 minute.

THANKS

```
package connection_mysql;
import java.sql.*;
```

`   public class Main {
      private static Connection connect = null;
      private static Statement statement = null;
      private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
      private static ResultSet resultSet = null;

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pilote = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    try{
        Class.forName(pilote);
        System.out.println("---------1------------------");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"
                  + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");
        Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement
                  .executeQuery("select * from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS");

        while(resultSet.next()){
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            System.out.println("nom etudiant "+resultSet.getString("myuser"));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("errooor"+e);
  }

  }

  }
```

Comment: You might want to add a bit more to the question ... any relevant code would help.  You will get a better and quicker response.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How many records do you have in your table? Is tour query a select? If yes, are you trying to load all data at once? Can you post your code? Also, a SQLFiddle might help

Comment: Is this local DB or remote and what is the time to execute simple `SELECT 1`?

Comment: I have local DB,and i don't have much records just one

Answer (score 0):

Database performance is predicated on schema design and the type of query being run, in addition to the amount and distribution of data in the various tables and their attributes. When you get really crazy, "out of bounds" performance, the first thing to check is that you've not done something silly like try to fetch a terrabyte of data through a super-slow link.

We'll need a LOT more information to be able to help you!

Your FIRST thing to do is try your access through the most simple tools available, like a "terminal monitor." If it performs badly there, you must look at your fundamentals.

Connection time should not be factored in with query execution time. Put time-stamps between the steps to see where the time lag is really going. Creating a new connection can be expensive though a full minute seems very excessive.

Answer (score 0):

If you think this is because of eclipse then run this program in console and check how much time it takes there. If it takes same time then there is problem with your JDBC Driver or Database.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: you guys should default 50 reputation when user creates an account.

Comment: The current system is intentional.  It discourages using the site as a discussion forum. It's a Q&A site.